# Service Heritage in Angular 5+

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-services

I'm trying to generalize and parameterize certain components and services in my application so that save time and code for common parts.

With the components I succeeded easily with the inheritance; but when trying the same maneuver with the services, I fail. Can someone help me see my mistake?

My ParentService its:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { URL } from '../constants';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {

constructor(public http: HttpClient, public name:string='category') {

}

returnData(url){
 return this.http.get(url);
}

getList():Observable<any>{
 var url = URL+'/'+this.name+'/list';
 console.log("-> URL: "+url);
 return this.returnData(url);
}

}
```

My SonService it´s like that:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { GlobalService } from './global.service';

@Injectable()
export class ActorService extends GlobalService{ 

  constructor (public http: HttpClient){
    super(http, 'actor');
  }
}
```

I imported all in app.module.ts, and included un providers (the first one it´s the globalService).

The error that i have in "ng build --prod" it´s:

```
ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for GlobalService in myDirectoryPath/global.service.ts: ([object Object], ?).
```

Comment: Do you inject `GlobalService` anywhere in your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to implement some sort of common service that holds some shared logic among your other services. I, also, assume you won't inject this `GlobalService` in any part of your application, just the ones that extends this one.

If this is your case, you should remove `@Injectable()` decorator from your `GlobalService`. What this does is to tell angular to try inject everything within its constructor. Angular knows how to inject `http`, but it does not know how to inject `name`.  So, if you remove `@Injectable()`, angular will ignore this service. Your other services will have `http` injected within their constructor (as you have shown in your code) and pass it to `GlobalService`.

Comment: Thank you; That was the solution. I just had to remove the GlobalService from the app.module.ts

Comment: @DoberDog you should delete `@Injectable()` from `GlobalService` as well. It might confuse those who look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a value to the second parameter, the "name" attribute, when you import this service.
That's what is being explained here: ([object Object], ?)

Take a look at the [official doc, where the DI is explained](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).
What you probably need is to use the 'useValue' when providing this service.

Or if you won't provide this value, just remove the second parameter.